# Add Custom Products (Paint Colors) To Woocommerce Cart Via Ajax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a paint store where customers can select a RAL color and choose quantity in liters.[image: Here is the product page]

The price is calculated based on the color recipe. Currently when a product is added, the price and product description are showed correctly.[image]

However when I try to pick up another color, it does not add the product in the cart. Here is the best custom code I could make so far:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item' , 'set_woo_prices');
add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session',  'set_session_prices', 10 , 3);

function set_woo_prices($woo_data) {
if (empty($_POST['kforwselectcolorprice'])) {
    return $woo_data; 
}

$woo_data['my_prod_name'] = $_POST['kforwselectcolorname'];
foreach ($_POST['kforwoo_variation_quantity'] as $prodVarName => $prodVarQty) {
    if (empty($prodVarQty)) {
        continue;
    }
    $woo_data['my_prod_name'] .= sprintf("<br/> %s x %d", $prodVarName, $prodVarQty);
}

$woo_data['my_price'] = $_POST['kforwselectcolorprice'];
$woo_data['data']->set_price($_POST['kforwselectcolorprice']);
$woo_data['data']->set_name($woo_data['my_prod_name']);

return $woo_data;
}

function set_session_prices($woo_data, $values, $key) {
if (empty($woo_data['my_price']) || empty($woo_data['my_prod_name'])) {
    return $woo_data; 
}
$woo_data['data']->set_price($woo_data['my_price']);
$woo_data['data']->set_name($woo_data['my_prod_name']);

return $woo_data;
}
```

Update: Only the first time a product is added the hook woocommerce_add_cart_item is called. On any consecutive calls, the hook is not executed...

Update2: I'm using the plugin Custom Paint Variation for WooCommerce

Answer (score 0):

They way I fixed it was adding this code above the existing one, so that the hook "woocommerce_add_cart_item" is called again:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'set_woo_prices_data', 10, 3);

function set_woo_prices_data($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
if (empty($_POST['kforwselectcolorprice'])) {
    return $cart_item_data; 
}
  $cart_item_data['kforwoo_product_id'] = $product_id;
  $cart_item_data['kforwselectcolor'] = $_POST['kforwselectcolor'];
  $cart_item_data['kforwcolorprice'] = $_POST['kforwselectcolorprice'];
  $cart_item_data['kforwoo_variation_quantity'] = $_POST['kforwoo_variation_quantity'];
  return $cart_item_data;
}
```